# Unreferenced native library not getting copied to application's published packages bin directory - visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, publish

I have a main application (web application) that consumes various other project (directly and chain). One of the projects happens to be Project named Parser. Parser project contains a dll, which is not refered as it is native dll. Properties of the dll file says Build Action: Content and  Copy to o/p directory: copy always.

Now when i do a build of my main aplication the native dll is copied to my applications bin and everything works great. But when I publish the application the packages bin does not contain the native dll.

My question is why is the dll not copied when I publish?

There is another project in the solution that has a folder within called temps, it contains a bunch of htm files. the properties of the files are Build Action: Content and  Copy to o/p directory: copy always.. In the published package these files and folders are present.

So why are the htm files copied and not the dll file? Are they treated any differently?

None of the projects have any pre or post build events.